# Can any one explain the bold sentance?

Tags: sentence-meaning, synonyms

I first met Che one day in July or August 1955. And in one night — **as he recalls in his account** — he became one of the future Granma expeditionaries, although at that time the expedition possessed neither ship, nor arms, nor troops. That was how, together with Raúl, Che became one of the first two on the Granma list.

Answer (score 1):

***as he recalls in his account*** means **as he tells us in his report**

---

**recall** verb (REMEMBER): to bring the memory of a past event into your mind, and often **to give a description of what you remember**: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recall?q=RECALLS)

**account** noun (REPORT): a written or spoken description of an event: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/account)

Answer (score 0):

It means something like the following:

> Che told a story.
> In his story, Che says that he became something in only one night
> That something, was one of the future Granma expeditionaries

The word "account" means "story" (or maybe "book")
In this context, "to recall" means "to describe."

---

If you...

> "**Recall** your birthday party in your **account**"

it means that you:

> "Describe your birthday party in your autobiography"